# How do I execute the rd command in Java?

Tags: java

How do I execute

> rd /s /q c:\folder

in Java?

It woks perfectly on the command-line.

Comment: It's worthy to look for a pure Java deltree solution like some posts suggest! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [dtsazza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857212/how-do-i-execute-rd-command-in-java/857220#857220):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k rd /s /q c:\\folder");
```

It works perfectly under WinXP SP3. The `/k` parameter shows, that a command will follow that has to be executed out of the `cmd.exe`.

Good luck with that!

Comment: Although of course you need to double up the backslash (c:\\folder)

Answer (score 5):

Check the [Runtime.exec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) method, which lets you call external processes.  (Bear in mind that you lose some platform independence as this would rely on the machine having the `rd` command installed and on the path.)

A better option might be to do the same thing in pure Java - the following should be equivalent:

```
private void deleteDirectory(File directory)
{
   for (File entity : directory.listFiles())
   {
      if (entity.isDirectory())
      {
         deleteDirectory(entity);
      }
      else
      {
         entity.delete();
      }
   }
   directory.delete();
}

deleteDirectory(new File("C:\\folder"));
```

Adding error-checking as required. :-)

Comment: rd is working fine on the command prompt but not through Runtime.exec() function.

Comment: implement it, like i described.

Comment: the recursion is cleaner in mine too - only one call to .delete() and no tests in the for() loop :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out FileUtils in Apache Commons-IO; in particular, the [deleteDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory(java.io.File)) and [deleteQuietly](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteQuietly(java.io.File)) methods, which can both recursively delete a directory.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `File.delete(String path)` method, i.e.:

```
new File("c:\\folder").delete();
```

If the `/s` (recursive) deletion is important, then (untested):

```
public void deltree(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
            deltree(f);
        }
    }
    file.delete();
}

public void deltree(String path) {
    deltree(new File(path));
}
```

invoked as:

```
deltree("c:\\folder");
```

Comment: this does not delete folder which contains files or/and folders.

Comment: File.delete() returns a boolean flag indicating whether the delete was successful rather than throwing an IOException; should you be checking this?

Comment: well, I _did_ say it was untested ;-)

Comment: Alnitak's solution worked for me. (I am checking the result of File.delete() per simonn's comment.)

Answer (score 1):

You only can delet empty directories in Java. First you have to delete the files and sub directories.

```
 public static boolean removeDirectoryRecursively(File dir) {
            if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                String[] children = dir.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    boolean success = removeDirectoryRecursively(new File(dir, children[i]));
                    if (!success) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            // The directory is now empty so delete it
            return dir.delete();
        }
```

Comment: File.listFiles() is far simpler

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute it exactly the way you specified, you can do

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k rd /s /q c:\\folder");
```